# ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) TagHelper Intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I created an ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) project and was expecting TagHelper Intellisense to work (just like a non-.Net Framework core project); but it does not work.

I see no intellisense such as, but not limited to: asp-for, asp-controller.

What am I missing?

ASP.Net Web Frameworks and Tools Extension Version: 5.2.40314.0

And here is my project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellisense has nothing to do with your project.json. It's entirely about having the appropriate tooling installed in the appropriate version of Visual Studio. The ASP.Net Web Frameworks and Tools Extension is for MVC 5, not Core, so that doesn't help you. You need [Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt752379.aspx) ([Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) must be installed first) with [.NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows) (at the time of this writing).

If you have all that, and it's still not working, then it might be a bug or simply unfinished. Remember that Core is still very much a work in progress, despite having a 1.0 release. The tooling, especially, is still very much in flux. You can follow the development of Visual Studio "15" to see how the tooling is coming along. All the tooling provided for Visual Studio 2015 (not to be confused with "15") is pretty much back-ported from the preview Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I verified that I had Update 3 along with Tooling Preview 2... so I guess I will have to wait until either 15 is released or a new version of the tooling for 2015 is back-ported. Bummer.

Comment: I opened an issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/846 .

Comment: @ChrisPratt I have the same issue with latest updates (you mentioned) already installed.

Comment: Thought I would update future visitors with the solution, which was to build the project. intellisense for tag helpers wont work until you build your project.

Comment: I can't get it to work with the updates and building first.